# Angular UI router permissions / access control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having a lot of trouble determining how to add permissions / access-control to our Angular app. Right now we have this:

```
    app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

      $stateProvider

      .state('default', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'pages/home/view/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })

      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'pages/home/view/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',

        permissions: {                    // ?
          only: ['Admin','Moderator']
        },

        access: {                         // ?
         roles: ['*']
        },

        resolve: {                        // ?
          authenticate: function($state, $q, $timeout){

          },

        }

      })

}]);
```

I having trouble determining which methodology to use to create access control to each page.

Right now, the logged in user is stored in an Angular value:

```
app.value('USER', JSON.parse('{{{user}}}'));
```

The USER value contains the information about which roles / permissions the user has.

But I cannot inject USER into `app.config()` callback, it says "unknown provider".

How can I do access-control based of the USER parameters?

Comment: `app.value()` cannot be injected into a config block. : https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099#value . Use `app.constant()` instead

Comment: cool, that's good to know, but for this case, using resolve.authenticate, we can inject anything, so don't need that solution tmk.

Comment: If you can update to UI-Router 1.0, a Transition Hook is the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: sure, add an answer and I will upvote

Answer (score 3):

the key to perform that is to add your access control on an event $stateChangeStart

For example if you have your routing like that :

```
      .state('termsofuse', {
            url: "/terms",
            templateUrl: "termOfUse.html",
            resolve: {
                authorizedRoles: function() {
                    return [USER_ROLES['su'],
                        USER_ROLES['user'],
                        USER_ROLES['admin'],
                        USER_ROLES['skysu']
                    ]
                }

            }

        })
```

you may define your access controle like that

```
.run(
            function($rootScope, $q, $location, $window, $timeout) {

                $rootScope.$on(
                    '$stateChangeStart',
                    function(event, next, current) {                      

                        var authorizedRoles = next.resolve.authorizedRoles();

//this function controls if user has necessary roles
                      if (!isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {

                            event.preventDefault();
      // and I broadcast the news                                                     $rootScope.$broadcast("AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated"); 


                        } else {
$rootScope.$broadcast("AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess");


                        }

                    })



            });
```

Then you just of to define your event's catcher to manager the desired behaviour (redirect / error message or whatever necessary)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [ngAA](https://github.com/lykmapipo/ngAA), I use it alongside ui-router.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work. I am not sure if it's the best way, but it does work.

You cannot inject services/values in the app.config(), but you can inject services/values into the resolve.authenticate function.

I decided to use the resolve.authenticate methodology.

```
 .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'pages/home/view/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    resolve: {
      authenticate: handlePageRequest['home']   // <<<<
    }
  })
```

and then we have a handler:

```
  let handlePageRequest = {

    'default': function ($q, USER, $state, $timeout, AuthService) {
      // this page is always ok to access
      return $q.when();
    },

    'home': function ($q, USER, $state, $timeout, AuthService) {

      if(AuthService.isHomePageAccessible(USER)){
        return $q.when();
      }
      else{
        $timeout(function () {
          $state.go('not-found'); // we can prevent user from accessing home page this way
        }, 100);

        return $q.reject()
      }
    },
  };
```